# When nested within if statement, start cmd not executing properly in windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

For whatever reason, this command works:

```
SET QUERY="heat wave"
START /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application" chrome.exe https://www.google.com/search?q=%QUERY: =+%
```

But this does not:

```
SET SWITCH=1
IF %SWITCH%==1 (
SET QUERY="heat wave"
START /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application" chrome.exe https://www.google.com/search?q=%QUERY: =+%
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here be would be to `enabledelayedexpansion`

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SET SWITCH=1
IF %SWITCH%==1 (
SET QUERY="heat wave"
START /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" https://www.google.com/search?q=!QUERY: =+!
)
```

For more on `delayedexpansion` do `set /?` from cmdline.

also possible without `delayedexpansion` by doubling the last `%` and calling start.

```
SET SWITCH=1
IF %SWITCH%==1 (
SET QUERY="heat wave"
call START /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" https://www.google.com/search?q=%%QUERY: =+%%
)
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to do anything. It still just opens google without any search being executed.

Comment: @OliverAngelil did you copy all my code or only added the top line? did you notice the `!QUERY: =+!` in the url in last line being `!` intead of `%`?

Comment: also, see the edit in my answer for using it without delayed expansnsion.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard It only works because chrome.exe is already in the path, otherwise it would fail because the first argument in double quotes is interpreted as the window title, see `start.exe /?`

Comment: @lotpings. I did not even notice that. I simply focused on the variable in the loop. Fixed. Thanks.